# ExtJS groupclick select all child elements on header click

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am trying to extend an open source automation testing framework which uses ExtJS.

I am new to ExtJS and have tried to play around around with its views.

Now I wish to use grid grouping in such a way that when I click on an icon on the group header, it should append all the data of its children in an array and fire that event in the controller along with the data.

I tried adding groupclick to my listeners but it does not seem to work.

Snapshot of my page looks like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LeMn.png

Following is my code of its view:

```
Ext.define('Redwood.view.Reportsgrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.reportsgrid',
    store: 'Reports',
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    title: "[All Executions]",
    features: [{
        ftype:'grouping',
        groupHeaderTpl: "Test Case Name: {name}",
        // enableGroupingMenu:true
    }],
    listeners:{
        groupclick: function (view, node, group, e, eOpts) {
            view.features[0].collapseAll();
            view.features[0].expand(group);
        }
    },
    viewConfig: {
        markDirty: false
    },
    minHeight: 150,
    height: 500,
    plugins: [
        "bufferedrenderer"],
    manageHeight: true,
    initComponent: function () {
        var reportsView = this;
        var me = this;
        this.tbar ={
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            items: [
            ]
        };
        this.columns = [
           /* {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                header: 'Action',
                width: 75,
                weight: 1,
                align: 'center',
                items: [
                    {
                        icon: 'images/symbol_sum.png',
                        tooltip: 'Aggregated Report',
                        itemId: "aggregationReport",
                        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                            var report = this.up("reportsView");
                            report.fireEvent('aggregate')
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }, */
            {
                header: 'Executions',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1,
                width: 200,
                weight: 2,
                summaryType: 'count',
                summaryRenderer: function(value,metaData,record){
                    return "<p style='font-weight:bold;color:#000000'>"+value+"</p>";
                }
            },
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`groupclick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.html#event-groupclick) event is available on the feature, not the grid, so you have to add your listener to the feature, not the grid:

```
features: [{
    ftype:'grouping',
    groupHeaderTpl: "Test Case Name: {name}",
    // enableGroupingMenu:true
    listeners:{
        groupclick: function (view, node, group, e, eOpts) {
            view.features[0].collapseAll();
            view.features[0].expand(group);
        }
    }
}],
```

Comment: I did try as you said, doesn't seem to work. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify whether groupClick is triggered or the code inside the groupClick is not working?. if the gridClick is triggered, try this.

```
 grid.doLayout();
```